# libc abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, facebook, xib

I'm trying to link Facebook with my app to get Profile Image and name. I'm following Facebook's tutorial and i'm having some problem with the very first login view.

When i try to run, that's the problem:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here's the tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

I'm frozen on step 2b.

Thank you very much

Comment: I got this same error also, no idea how to solve yet.